# C#5.0のasync/awaitに関してtask.Start()を実行した後のawait task; の挙動がよくわからない

Tags: c#

C#5.0のasync/awaitを学習しています。

下記のコンソールアプリケーションが期待した動作と異なる動きをします。
理由を教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestAsync().Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task TestAsync()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var task = new Task(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("3. elapsed={0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine("4. elapsed={0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
            });

        Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1. elapsed={0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine("2. elapsed={0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
                task.Start(); // ここでtask処理開始
            });

        await task;

        Console.WriteLine("5. elapsed={0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
    }
}
```

### 期待する出力

```
1. elapsed=0
2. elapsed=1
3. elapsed=1
4. elapsed=2
5. elapsed=2
```

### 実際の出力

Visual Studio 2015 Community で実行しました。

```
1. elapsed=0
2. elapsed=1
3. elapsed=1
5. elapsed=1
4. elapsed=2
```

※4と5が期待とは逆
※5の出力が期待より1秒早い。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Run`とは異なり`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`のコンストラクターは非同期メソッドに対応していません。このため引数のデリゲートは戻り値のタスクを無視して同期実行され、`Task.Delay`が開始されたタイミングで`task`は完了状態になります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

async void と同様の動作になってしまうんですね。
コンストラクタではTask<Func>を引数に受け取れるわけでもなく
task.Start() が完了待ちを知るためのTaskを返せるわけでもない。

理解できました。